# Inequality with this HP sum to $ \frac{1}{2^n -1 }$ is greater than $ \frac{n}{2}$ but less than $n $

Tags: sequences-and-series

> For any $ n \in \mathbb N$ , let $$ f(n) = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} +\dots+ \frac{1}{2^n -1 } ,$$ then show that $$ \frac{n}{2} ≤ f(n) < n $$

Now in this question, the main problem I that this is in HP, how would I sum it up ?? Maybe in higher mathematics there are ways, but I am still in highschool , and that is why I suppose there should be some way other way around this problem ,but I can't figure out any way. Please help

Also more than the answer of it, I would love to know the thought process behind it. How do you come up with it.  ( Like some sort of hint that point into that Direction. ) Thank You

Comment: Try bounding the series. If $2^a \leq k \leq 2^{a+1}$ then $$\frac1{2^a} \geq \frac1k \geq \frac{1}{2^{a+1}}.$$

Comment: Could you integrate for 1/x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$f(n)= \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \biggl(\,\underbrace{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}}_{>2\cdot\tfrac14}\,\biggr) + \biggl(\,\underbrace{\frac{1}{5}+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18}_{>4\cdot\tfrac18}\,\biggr)+\dotsm$$
and also
$$f(n)= \frac{1}{1} + \biggl(\,\underbrace{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}}_{<2\cdot\tfrac12}\,\biggr) + \biggl(\,\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}+\frac 15+\frac16+\frac17}_{<4\cdot\tfrac14}\,\biggr)+\biggl(\frac18 +\dotsm\biggr)+\dots+\biggl(\dotsm+ \frac{1}{2^n -1}\biggr).$$

Comment: How do you come up with that thought ??

Comment: It's just a variation on a standard elementary proof of the divergence of the harmonic series.

Comment: Okay. Thank You...